The object of type 'CanvasRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it./Unity.iOS
On the iOS version of my unity game (not in the android one), and with Unity 2022.3.27f1, An hard-reproducible error occurs, and all buttons stops to play:
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'CanvasRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast (UnityEngine.Canvas canvas, UnityEngine.Camera eventCamera, UnityEngine.Vector2 pointerPosition, System.Collections.Generic.IList1[T] foundGraphics, System.Collections.Generic.List1[T] results) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/GraphicRaycaster.cs:317)
UnityEngine.UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData, System.Collections.Generic.List1[T] resultAppendList) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/UI/Core/GraphicRaycaster.cs:218) UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.RaycastAll (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData, System.Collections.Generic.List1[T] raycastResults) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:276)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerInputModule.GetTouchPointerEventData (UnityEngine.Touch input, System.Boolean& pressed, System.Boolean& released) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/PointerInputModule.cs:98)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessTouchEvents () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/StandaloneInputModule.cs:305)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/InputModules/StandaloneInputModule.cs:281)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:530)
I think it is an Event system error, but I don't understand what causes this error. WHAT CanvasRenderer has been destroyed, since All the canvas renderers of my hyerarchy are not destroyed. Should it be a Unity/iOS error? I searched on many forums but no clear answers
